# Pull back motor 552 x2

Tags: motor, wheel

I have these wheels and want to find a set/booklet where it is used.
No combination of the numbers give any result.
It says Lego Group 2011 
522 x2[image]

Found it

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks very much like pullback of the promotional LEGO sets with ferrari an shell from 2012.

They have got the set numbers 30190 to 30195 and there is an additional crew pack (30196).

Comment: PS: how did you get to that conclusion? Part number or just knowledge? I could not find _6009407: Pull-Back 4X8X2/3_ anywhere on the part

Comment: The part is from 2011 so it is most likely in a 2011/12 set. I knew there were some pullback cars with ferrari. After a quick use of google and a short look in the instructions -> voilà